# Kubernetes Access Windows Environment Variable

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices

How i can access or read windows environment variable in kubernetes. I achieved the same in docker compose file.

How i can do the same in kubernetes as i am unable to read the windows environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the standard Kubernetes ecosystem can be configured using host environment variables.

If you're using the core `kubectl` tool, the YAML files you'd feed into `kubectl apply` are self-contained manifests; they cannot depend on host files or environment variables.  This can be wrapped in a second tool, [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io), which can apply some modifications, but that explicitly [does not support host environment variables](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/faq/kustomize/eschewedfeatures/#build-time-side-effects-from-cli-args-or-env-variables).  [Helm](https://helm.sh) lets you build Kubernetes manifests using a templating language, but that also specifically [does not use host environment variables](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#know-your-template-functions).

You'd need to somehow inject the environment variable value into one of these deployment systems.  With all three of these tools, you could include those in a file (a Kubernetes YAML manifest, a Kustomize overlay, a Helm values file) that could be checked into source control; you may also be able to retrieve these values from some sort of external storage.  But just relaying host environment variables into a container isn't an option in Kubernetes.

Comment: Thanks David, i appreciate your response. I did the same thing and injected the values inside the deployment YAML file of Kubernetes.